# Deleting a contact from a phone book code in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Having trouble deleting a contact from my phone book code. The other functions work just fine, but when I go to delete a contact it just stops the program.

I've tried looking up different examples, but haven't found anything that has worked for me yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct contact {                // Data structure that holds contact information 
    char FirstName[10];         // Array for first name
    char LastName[10];          // Array for last name
    int PhoneNum;               // Phone number
};

int main() {

    // Setting up variables
    int Function = 0;
    int Choice = 0;
    char FName[200][10];
    char LName[200][10];
    int PNum = 0;
    int n = 1;
    int size = 1;
    struct contact *con = (struct contact *)malloc(size * sizeof(struct contact));
    int b = 0, a = 0;
    int DelCon = 0;

    do {     // Will loop through the main function until the user decides to exit the program

        // Prints out the main menu of the phone book
        printf("\nPhone Book");
        printf("\n[1] Add a contact");
        printf("\n[2] Delete a contact");
        printf("\n[3] Show contacts");
        printf("\n[4] Exit program");
        printf("\n\nWhat function would you like to use?\n");       // Asks for user input
        scanf("%d", &Choice);

        switch (Choice) {
        case 1:     // Case to add a contact into the phone book
            printf("\nYou chose to add a contact.");
            printf("\nFirst name: ");
            scanf("%s", &FName[b]);
            printf("\nLast name: ");
            scanf("%s", &LName[b]);
            printf("\nPhone number (Numbers only): ");
            scanf("%d", &PNum);
            printf("\nRecord added to the phone book");

            // Records the information given into the structure
            if (n >= size)
            {
                size = size * 2;
                con = (struct contact*)realloc(con, size * sizeof(struct contact));
            }
            a = (n - 1);

            strcpy(con[a].FirstName, FName[b]);
            strcpy(con[a].LastName, LName[b]);
            con[a].PhoneNum = PNum;

            b = (b + 1);
            n++;

            // Prints out the given information
            printf("\n\nNew contact:");
            printf("\nFirst name: %s", con[a].FirstName);
            printf("\nLast name: %s", con[a].LastName);
            printf("\nPhone number: %d", con[a].PhoneNum);
            printf("\nContact number is %d", a);
            printf("\n");
            break;
        case 2:     // Case to delete a contact from the phone book
            printf("\nYou chose to delete a contact.");
            printf("\nWhich contact would you like to delete? Specify by contact number. ");
            scanf("%d", &DelCon);
            a = DelCon;
            char DelF = 0;
            char DelL = 0;
            int DelNum = 0;
            strcpy(con[a].FirstName, DelF);
            strcpy(con[a].LastName, DelL);
            strcpy(con[a].PhoneNum, DelNum);
            printf("\nContact deleted");
            printf("\n");
            break;
        case 3:     // Case to see all of the entered contacts
            printf("\nYou chose to show the contacts.");
            for (a = 0; a < (n - 1); a++) {
                printf("\nContact #%d", a);
                printf("\nFirst name: %s", con[a].FirstName);
                printf("\nLast name: %s", con[a].LastName);
                printf("\nPhone number: %d", con[a].PhoneNum);
                printf("\n");
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Goodbye!");
            break;
        }
    } while (Choice != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what my code printed out.

```
Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program

What function would you like to use?
1

You chose to add a contact.
First name: test

Last name: 1

Phone number (Numbers only): 1234567

Record added to the phone book

New contact:
First name: test
Last name: 1
Phone number: 1234567
Contact number is 0

Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program

What function would you like to use?
1

You chose to add a contact.
First name: Test

Last name: 2

Phone number (Numbers only): 8901234

Record added to the phone book

New contact:
First name: Test
Last name: 2
Phone number: 8901234
Contact number is 1

Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program

What function would you like to use?
3

You chose to show the contacts.
Contact #0
First name: test
Last name: 1
Phone number: 1234567

Contact #1
First name: Test
Last name: 2
Phone number: 8901234

Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program

What function would you like to use?
2

You chose to delete a contact.
Which contact would you like to delete? Specify by contact number. 0

--------------------------------
Process exited with return value 3221225477
```

It should be deleting the contact and returning back to the menu.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Your code contains [too many errors](https://ideone.com/NtM3cn). You are either ignoring warnings or compiling with warnings supressed. Both are extremely poor practices. You should enable all warnings and treat all warnings as errors. Once you have code that compiles cleanly, you can start testing it.

Comment: If I fix the 3 invalid _strcpy_ signaled by the compiler the sequence of commands you give works, look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Process exited with return value 3221225477

The first thing to do when compiling is to ask for the max warning level, if I do `gcc -pedantic -Wextra` on your code the compiler signals these lines :

> ```
>        char DelF = 0;
>        char DelL = 0;
>        int DelNum = 0;
>        strcpy(con[a].FirstName, DelF);
>        strcpy(con[a].LastName, DelL);
>        strcpy(con[a].PhoneNum, DelNum);
> ```

the *strcpy* are wrong because the second parameter is a *char/int* while a *char** (with a null ending character) is expected, the behavior is undefined, in your case a crash. Note that *PhoneNum* is an *int* rather than an array of char so it is worst for it if I can say.

If the goal is to empty the 2 strings and reset phone number just do :

```
con[a].FirstName[0] = 0;
con[a].LastName[0] = 0;
con[a].PhoneNum = 0;
```

After these corrections the execution is :

```
Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program

What function would you like to use?
1

You chose to add a contact.
First name: test

Last name: 1

Phone number (Numbers only): 1234567

Record added to the phone book

New contact:
First name: test
Last name: 1
Phone number: 1234567
Contact number is 0

Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program

What function would you like to use?
1

You chose to add a contact.
First name: Test

Last name: 2

Phone number (Numbers only): 8901234

Record added to the phone book

New contact:
First name: Test
Last name: 2
Phone number: 8901234
Contact number is 1

Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program

What function would you like to use?
3

You chose to show the contacts.
Contact #0
First name: test
Last name: 1
Phone number: 1234567

Contact #1
First name: Test
Last name: 2
Phone number: 8901234

Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program

What function would you like to use?
2

You chose to delete a contact.
Which contact would you like to delete? Specify by contact number. 0

Contact deleted

Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program
```

However the contact is not really *deleted*, it is still present even emptied in your list, if I do the command 3 after the delete that gives :

```
You chose to show the contacts.
Contact #0
First name: 
Last name: 
Phone number: 0

Contact #1
First name: Test
Last name: 2
Phone number: 8901234
```

You need to remove the entry from *con*. You also need to check the validity of the rank of the element to remove.

Note that *n* is *strange* because it doesn't not contain the number of entries but one more, when the book is empty it already values 1, then 2 etc.

*b* is redundant with *n* because it values `n-1`. It is an index to *FName* and *LName* but I don't see the interest of these two 2D arrays, you can directly *scanf* into *con* or just define them as a simple array of characters. The best way is to remove *b* and *FName* and *LName*.

*DelCon* is useless too because it is just an intermediate to set *a*.

*Function* is never used.

When you *scanf* a string limit the size of the input string to not take the risk to go out of the receiver.

---

A modified version taken into account my previous remark is :

```
int main() {

    // Setting up variables
    int Choice = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int size = 1;
    struct contact *con = (struct contact *)malloc(size * sizeof(struct contact));
    int a;

    do {     // Will loop through the main function until the user decides to exit the program

        // Prints out the main menu of the phone book
        printf("\nPhone Book");
        printf("\n[1] Add a contact");
        printf("\n[2] Delete a contact");
        printf("\n[3] Show contacts");
        printf("\n[4] Exit program");
        printf("\n\nWhat function would you like to use?\n");       // Asks for user input
        scanf("%d", &Choice);

        switch (Choice) {
        case 1:     // Case to add a contact into the phone book
            if (n == size)
            {
                size = size * 2;
                con = (struct contact*)realloc(con, size * sizeof(struct contact));
            }
            // Records the information given into the structure
            printf("\nYou chose to add a contact.");
            printf("\nFirst name: ");
            scanf("%9s", con[n].FirstName);
            printf("\nLast name: ");
            scanf("%9s", con[n].LastName);
            printf("\nPhone number (Numbers only): ");
            scanf("%d", &con[n].PhoneNum);
            printf("\nRecord added to the phone book");

            // Prints out the given information
            printf("\n\nNew contact:");
            printf("\nFirst name: %s", con[n].FirstName);
            printf("\nLast name: %s", con[n].LastName);
            printf("\nPhone number: %d", con[n].PhoneNum);
            printf("\nContact number is %d", n);
            printf("\n");
            n += 1;
            break;
        case 2:     // Case to delete a contact from the phone book
            printf("\nYou chose to delete a contact.");
            printf("\nWhich contact would you like to delete? Specify by contact number. ");
            scanf("%d", &a);
            if ((a < 0) || (a >= n))
              printf("\ninvalid rank of contact");
            else {
              /* if you do not have bcopy use memmove */
              bcopy(&con[a+1], &con[a], (n - 1 - a) * sizeof(struct contact));
              n -= 1;
              printf("\nContact deleted");
            }
            printf("\n");
            break;
        case 3:     // Case to see all of the entered contacts
            printf("\nYou chose to show the contacts.");
            for (a = 0; a < n; a++) {
                printf("\nContact #%d", a);
                printf("\nFirst name: %s", con[a].FirstName);
                printf("\nLast name: %s", con[a].LastName);
                printf("\nPhone number: %d", con[a].PhoneNum);
                printf("\n");
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            puts("\nGoodbye!");
            break;
        default:
            puts("\ninvalid choice");
        }
    } while (Choice != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra b.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program

What function would you like to use?
1

You chose to add a contact.
First name: test

Last name: 1

Phone number (Numbers only): 1234567

Record added to the phone book

New contact:
First name: test
Last name: 1
Phone number: 1234567
Contact number is 0

Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program

What function would you like to use?
1

You chose to add a contact.
First name: Test

Last name: 2

Phone number (Numbers only): 8901234

Record added to the phone book

New contact:
First name: Test
Last name: 2
Phone number: 8901234
Contact number is 1

Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program

What function would you like to use?
3

You chose to show the contacts.
Contact #0
First name: test
Last name: 1
Phone number: 1234567

Contact #1
First name: Test
Last name: 2
Phone number: 8901234

Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program

What function would you like to use?
2

You chose to delete a contact.
Which contact would you like to delete? Specify by contact number. 2

invalid rank of contact

Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program

What function would you like to use?
2

You chose to delete a contact.
Which contact would you like to delete? Specify by contact number. 0

Contact deleted

Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program

What function would you like to use?
3

You chose to show the contacts.
Contact #0
First name: Test
Last name: 2
Phone number: 8901234

Phone Book
[1] Add a contact
[2] Delete a contact
[3] Show contacts
[4] Exit program

What function would you like to use?
4

Goodbye!
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for the feedback. How would I be able to remove the entry though?

Comment: @CatyBattjes you can use _memmove_ or _bcopy_ to not have to copy the elements one by one to suppress the element (except if it is the last of course), of course _n_ as also to be updated

Comment: @CatyBattjes I edited my answer to add remarks and a proposal taken them into account including to remove a deleted entry rather than to just empty it

Comment: Thank you so much!